# Error: "HttpGetData.Type doesn't have a member named 'url'"

Tags: swift

I want to test HTTP POST, but it shows this error:

> HttpGetData.Type 'doesn't have a member named 'url'

When I type this on ViewController it works?

Is it an initialize problem?

```
import Foundation
public class HttpGetData{

    let url = NSURL( string: "https://210.61.209.194:8443/SmarttvWebServiceTopmsoApi/")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest((URL : url)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString : String = "id=13&name=Jack"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        println("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: it will still  show HttpGetData.Type 'dose not have a member named 'url'

Comment: You have to move that code into a (class or instance) *method* ...

Comment: Do you know what class/type and instance methods are in Swift? Otherwise I would recommend to read the Swift book first.

Comment: I type this in my viewController 
 let httpPost  = HttpGetData()
but it still show the same error